# Making openshift origin docker containers persistent after reboot

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am new to openshift and need to know if it is possible to make all containers in openshift origin persistent after restarting the oc cluster or rebooting the server.

The tutorial i followed requires one do the following in order to create a cluster

```
oc cluster up
```

The problem i am running into now is that login into my openshift application after, doing an `oc cluster down && oc cluser up` doesn't show any of my running containers.

I tried restarting all of them by doing a `docker start $(docker ps -qa)` but the containers still aren't showing up in the openshift origin application.

Any advice on how to resolve this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell it to persist the etcd and configuration data across restarts. See:

- https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#configuration
- https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#etcd-data

Where you tell it to save data may depend on whether you are using the local Docker service directly or docker-machine.

Comment: Thank you. `oc cluster up --host-data-dir='/path/to/createddir'` was what i needed.

Comment: You may also need ``--host-config-dir`` depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Links doesn't work anymore. Here is the new one
https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v3.11.0/docs/cluster_up_down.md