# How to make oc cluster up persistent?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

I'm using "oc cluster up" to start my Openshift Origin environment. I can see, however, that once I shutdown the cluster my projects aren't persisted at restart. Is there a way to make them persistent ?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making openshift origin docker containers persistent after reboot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539780/making-openshift-origin-docker-containers-persistent-after-reboot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. oc cluster up doesn't have a primary use case of persisting resources.

There are couple ways to do it:

- Leverage capturing etcd as described in the [oc cluster up README](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v3.11.0/docs/cluster_up_down.md#etcd-data)
- There is a [wrapper tool](https://github.com/openshift-evangelists/oc-cluster-wrapper), that makes it easy to do this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it Steve!

Comment: First doesn't work anymore. Here is the new one
https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v3.11.0/docs/cluster_up_down.md#etcd-data

Answer (score 4):

There is now an example in the `cluster up --help` command, it is bound to stay up to date so check that first

```
oc cluster up --help

...


Examples:

  # Start OpenShift on a new docker machine named 'openshift'
  oc cluster up --create-machine

  # Start OpenShift using a specific public host name
  oc cluster up --public-hostname=my.address.example.com

  # Start OpenShift and preserve data and config between restarts
  oc cluster up --host-data-dir=/mydata --use-existing-config
```

So specifically in `v1.3.2` use `--host-data-dir` and `--use-existing-config`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using docker machine with vm such as virtual box, the easiest way I found is taking a vm snapshot WHILE vm and openshift cluster are up and running. This snapshot will backup memory in addition to disk therefore you can restore entire cluster later on by restoring the vm snapshot, then run `docker-machine start ...`

btw, as of latest os image openshift/origin:v3.6.0-rc.0 and oc cli, `--host-data-dir=/mydata` as suggested in the other answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Using persistence on Windows is harder with recent versions of OpenShift due to etcd changes. An alternate wrapper script at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/powershift-cluster handles it though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

VirtualBox 5.1.26 
Kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
openshift v1.5.0+031cbe4

Didn't work for me using --host-data-dir (and others) :

```
oc cluster up  --logging=true --metrics=true --docker-machine=openshift --use-existing-config=true --host-data-dir=/vm/data --host-config-dir=/vm/config --host-pv-dir=/vm/pv --host-volumes-dir=/vm/volumes
```

With output:

```
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Checking Docker client ...
   Starting Docker machine 'openshift'
   Started Docker machine 'openshift'
-- Checking Docker version ...
   WARNING: Cannot verify Docker version
-- Checking for existing OpenShift container ... OK
-- Checking for openshift/origin:v1.5.0 image ... OK
-- Checking Docker daemon configuration ... OK
-- Checking for available ports ... OK
-- Checking type of volume mount ...
   Using Docker shared volumes for OpenShift volumes
-- Creating host directories ... OK
-- Finding server IP ...
   Using docker-machine IP 192.168.99.100 as the host IP
   Using 192.168.99.100 as the server IP
-- Starting OpenShift container ...
   Starting OpenShift using container 'origin'
FAIL
   Error: could not start OpenShift container "origin"
   Details:
     Last 10 lines of "origin" container log:
     github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/pkg/capnslog.(*PackageLogger).Panicf(0xc4202a1600, 0x42b94c0, 0x1f, 0xc4214d9f08, 0x2, 0x2)
        /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/_output/local/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/pkg/capnslog/pkg_logger.go:75 +0x16a
     github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend.newBackend(0xc4209f84c0, 0x33, 0x5f5e100, 0x2710, 0xc4214d9fa8)
        /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/_output/local/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend/backend.go:106 +0x341
     github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend.NewDefaultBackend(0xc4209f84c0, 0x33, 0x461e51, 0xc421471200)
        /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/_output/local/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/mvcc/backend/backend.go:100 +0x4d
     github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver.NewServer.func1(0xc4204bf640, 0xc4209f84c0, 0x33, 0xc421079a40)
        /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/_output/local/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/server.go:272 +0x39
     created by github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver.NewServer
        /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/_output/local/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdserver/server.go:274 +0x345
```

Openshift  writes to the directories /vm/... (also defined in VirtualBox) but successfully won't start. 
See [https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/12602][1]

Worked for me too, using Virtual Box Snapshots and restoring them.

Answer (score 0):

To make it persistent after each shutdown you need to provide `base-dir` parameter.

```
$ mkdir ~/openshift-config
$ oc cluster up --base-dir=~/openshift-config
```

From help

```
$ oc cluster up --help
...
Options:
--base-dir='': Directory on Docker host for cluster up configuration
--enable=[*]: A list of components to enable.  '*' enables all on-by-default components, 'foo' enables the component named 'foo', '-foo' disables the component named 'foo'.
--forward-ports=false: Use Docker port-forwarding to communicate with origin container. Requires 'socat' locally.
--http-proxy='': HTTP proxy to use for master and builds
--https-proxy='': HTTPS proxy to use for master and builds
--image='openshift/origin-${component}:${version}': Specify the images to use for OpenShift
--no-proxy=[]: List of hosts or subnets for which a proxy should not be used
--public-hostname='': Public hostname for OpenShift cluster
--routing-suffix='': Default suffix for server routes
--server-loglevel=0: Log level for OpenShift server
--skip-registry-check=false: Skip Docker daemon registry check
--write-config=false: Write the configuration files into host config dir
```

But you shouln't use it, because "cluster up" is removed in version 4.0.0. More here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/21399